# Convert Date/Time Text String to Time Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am running a report on a website that spits this out in a CSV format:

**Thu May 07 2020 12:16:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)**

I want to convert it to a time format in Excel, ideally MM:SS (no hours needed). I need to be able to add/subtract two times.

Tried various formulas, but the string is so long I keep confusing myself. Can someone assist?

Comment: thanks for your post. Just some tips on getting help from other developers is to ensure your question is clear and that you post examples of what you have tried as well. I find screenshots or code examples are a big help for people to understand exactly what you are trying to do, sometimes its hard to describe your problem. I would suggest editing your question and adding a screenshot of your cell in Excel and then a code snippet with the formulas you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)-2,8))
```

[image]

with the proper formatting.

Comment: @ba1234evr you can also apply the format directly to the cell with `TEXT(above formula, "mm:ss")`

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much @urdearboy and Gary's Student!